# How to show image as map in mapbox and use custom scale for it

Tags: dictionary, mapbox

I am trying to use image as a map in mapbox. I have to upload a image of a floor. It is to be shown as floor map with its own custom scale.

For showing the image I have used the following code:

```
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', '',) .fitBounds(imageBounds);    
L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds).addTo(map);
```

It is showing the image but now I want to change the scale. How can I do this as the **L.control.scale** api does not provide anything to change the measurements ?